# Complex CSS Selector - Use "and" with class selector

Tags: html, css

I would like to achieve the equivalent CSS selection of the following, without out the parenthesizes though since parenthesizes can not be used to change the order of operations in CSS.

```
.portion-of-html (thead,tfoot).stripe {
```

In English, an element who has an ancestor with the class `.portion-of-html`, can either be a `tfoot` element or a `thead` element, and also has the class `.stripe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove parentheses if your repeat code, it's like distributive property in math:

```
.portion-of-html thead.stripe, .portion-of-html tfoot.stripe
```

Comment: Okay, this works but I am a little confused on why this works. When evaluating from right to left you get to the `,` and say to yourself again also has the class `.stripe` and is a `thead` element. As in it has to be a `thead` elment and a `tfoot` element. Or is the entire left of the `,` evaluated as one piece?

Comment: @MarcM. The selector matches `thead` elements with class `stripe` which are descendants of an element with class `portion-of-html`, or `tfoot` elements with class `stripe` which are descendants of an element with class `portion-of-html`. Comma in CSS behaves like `(.portion-of-html thead.stripe), (.portion-of-html tfoot.stripe)`

Answer (score 0):

In pure CSS I think you just need to write each case out comma separated.

```
.portion-of-html thead.stripe, .portion-of-html tfoot.strip {
```

You may want to look into LESS.  It is fairly simple and you could write the selector like so..

```
.portion-of-html {
    styles: values; 
    thead.stripe, tbody.stripe { 
        styles: values; 
    } 
}
```

LESS compiles down to pure css.  You can process less files on the client with a js library, or you can process them before hand and send pure css down to the client which is my preference.

I've found that less allows me to construct styles in the same nested/xml style format as my HTML.  It helps to normalize my work process.
There is also SASS but I'm not familiar with that.